# Wordpress next_post_link/previous_post_link not staying in same category

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's my setup.

single.php

```
<?php

    if ( in_category( 'my-category' ) ) {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-my-category.php' );
    }
    else {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-generic.php' );
    }
?>
```

single-my-category.php

```
<?php

if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php echo the_title(); ?>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="next col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php next_post_link( '%link', '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-left.png" /> PREVIOUS', true ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="previous col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'NEXT <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-right.png" />', true ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This is what i have followed - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here as for some reason the previous_post_link is taking me to a post in a different category even though in_same_term parameter of the function is set to true.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This happens because you have multiple categories on your post and wp just goes to what ever is the first in the post (guess). Check [this link here](http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2010/06/02/stay-in-category/). Also  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005646/629127) could be helpful.

Comment: The post is only assigned to 1 category

Comment: you may try the pagination link underneath of loop

Comment: Are you sure that this post is assigned to only 1 category? Is it possible that it is still assigned to Uncategorized? It's a category too, and it has the lowest ID in the database.

Comment: Also, I hope you are not using a cache plugin.

Comment: Two questions, are you using the build-in taxonomy `category`, and which WordPress version are you using

Comment: The post is only associated with 1 category - this has been triple checked. WordPress version is 4.4.2 (latest stable release) and i'm using categories that I have created through WordPress. Also no, I'm not using any cache plugins. Thanks

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working perfectly without any issues.

Comment: So your next/previous links are going to posts only of the same category? Because mine aren't. I've tried on various different computers on different networks and I have the same issue. Cache has been cleared from everything as well numerous time.

Comment: You have something that is breaking the main query or `$post`. In all probability, you have custom query that does not use `wp_reset_postdata()` , or you, your theme or a pluugin is using `query_posts`. Do `var_dump( $wp_query );` and `var_dump( $post );` through out the templates and make sure that those values do not change

Comment: Also, why are you passing `$post` to `WP_Query`. What is `$post`. `$post` is a reserved global variable, breaking it will break thnousands of other applications relying on it, like navigation functions

Comment: Your last update is of no use

Comment: did you run in main theme or child theme?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code blocks as following. You haven't put '.php' on the 5th line of your single.php file. Previous/Next post will be shown only for the posts of category which you specify inside `if` statement of single.php ( here category 'php' ). For the following example, I've created a directory 'template-parts' and created two php file ("single-my-category.php" and "single-generic.php")inside that directory.

single.php

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $post );

    if (in_category('php')) {
        include( 'template-parts/single-my-category.php' );
    } else {
        include( 'template-parts/single-generic.php' );
    }
?>
```

single-my-category.php

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="next col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php next_post_link( '%link', '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-left.png" /> PREVIOUS', true ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="previous col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'NEXT <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-right.png" />', true ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this is actually an error on my part. I've trimmed down the question to make it easier for everyone to see what i've done and i've accidentally left out '.php' from the end. In the code it does actually have '.php' at the end of the template name. I'll edit this in my question now.

Comment: @AndrewMatthew I hink you have left out very important info here. Your code works perfectly fine, so something else not posted is breaking your code

Comment: `next_post_link()` & `previous_post_link()` take five parameters. Fourth one is $excluded_terms and Fifth one is $taxonomy (default value is 'category'). Could you try adding two more params to both functions? 4th will be  '' and 5th will be 'category'. [Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/)

Answer (score 1):

Also specify the category name in single page .. since single-categoryname.php is not correct you should try using taxonomy-taxonomy_name.php OR

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=CATEGORYNAME&showposts=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<div class="pagination">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="next col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <?php next_post_link( '%link', '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-left.png" /> PREVIOUS', true ); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="previous col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'NEXT <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-right.png" />', true ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If **in_same_term** is not working for you, It might your query object is not holding up the post data.

Give it a try -

```
global $the_query;
$the_query = new WP_Query( $post );
```

---

```
global $the_query;
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="next col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php next_post_link( '%link', '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-left.png" /> PREVIOUS', true ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="previous col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'NEXT <img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/cs-right.png" />', true ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you plz add this code in your **template file**.

```
<ul class="pager">
  <?php if ( get_previous_post() != null ) : ?>
    <li class="previous">
      <span class="nav-previous">
        <?php 
          $singular_nav_previous_text = apply_filters( 'tc_singular_nav_previous_text', _x( '&larr;' , 'Previous post link' , 'customizr' ) );
          previous_post_link( '%link' , '<span class="meta-nav">' . $singular_nav_previous_text . '</span> %title' ); 
        ?>
      </span>
    </li>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ( get_next_post() != null ) : ?>
    <li class="next">
      <span class="nav-next">
        <?php
          $singular_nav_next_text = apply_filters( 'tc_singular_nav_next_text', _x( '&rarr;' , 'Next post link' , 'customizr' ) );
          next_post_link( '%link' , '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . $singular_nav_next_text . '</span>' ); 
          ?>
      </span>
    </li>
  <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Now add below code in **function.php**

```
add_filter('tc_previous_single_post_link_args', 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy');
add_filter('tc_next_single_post_link_args', 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy');
function navigate_in_same_taxonomy( $args ){
  $args['in_same_term'] = true;
  return $args;
}
```

if you need more option on Next/Prev link check [this link](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/restrict-post-navigation-category/)

Comment: These are Customizr specific hooks. Not wordpress, this won't work.

Comment: Stackoverflows expired bounty selection process gave the bounty to this answer. This 'solution' DOES NOT WORK. Thanks.